# Check for level change while traversing folder using nftw()

Tags: c, file-handling, nftw

I am trying to recursively iterate a folder using the nftw() function of C for printing the complete Directory Structure along with that I can't find a way to check whether the level has changed ,i.e, it has moved inside a directory or is iterating in the directory only. So, is there any way I can check for change in level using nftw()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the POSIX specification of [`nftw()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nftw.html), you'll find:

> At each file it encounters, `nftw()` shall call the user-supplied function `fn` with four arguments:
>
> - The first argument is the pathname of the object.
> - The second argument is a pointer to the stat buffer containing information on the object…
> - The third argument is an integer giving additional information. Its value is one of the following:
>
>   - `FTW_D` — The object is a directory.
>   - …
> - The fourth argument is a pointer to an `FTW` structure. The value of `base` is the offset of the object's filename in the pathname passed as the first argument to `fn`. The value of `level` indicates depth relative to the root of the walk, where the root level is 0.

So, the answer to your question is that the `level` element of the FTW object tells you the level of the current item.  If you need to spot changes, you'll need to keep track of the previous level, somehow — it likely will be a file scope variable.

It would be nice if there was a variant of `nftw()` (call it `nftw2()`) that made provision for a user-supplied 'extra information' argument — a `void *` that would be passed to `nftw2()` and which `nftw2()` would relay to the called function.  Then you'd not need the file scope variable.

The BSD, macOS and Linux systems, at least, have an alternative to `nftw()` — the [`fts(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fts.3.html) functions (also at [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=fts_open&apropos=0&sektion=3&manpath=FreeBSD+10-current&format=html)).  The macOS manual says they might be a part of a future version of POSIX, but they're not a part of POSIX 2017.  (I don't see the extra information parameter here, either — oh well!  If you're ever designing a callback system, consider providing a context (or 'extra information') parameter that can be used.)